# Checking to see if Html Input textfield has value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On my asp.net web app (mvc), **I am wanting to check if the user entered a value in the text field when the button is clicked, and if it is to redirect to the next page. If not, to throw an exception.** I looked up on how to do so, and attempted to use it with `Html.BeginForm()` but for some reason it still does enter my condition statement when I leave the textbox blank and hit the submit button.

**ORIGINAL CODE:**

SecondController:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Insert(String inputF)
        {
          
            if (inputF == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("You did not type anything in the textfield!!!!");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("FinalIndex", "Final");
            }
        }
```

I wanted it to throw an exception but not stop the program for proceeding like it return a message to the user in the UI but still record the exception that was made.

***UPDATED CODE:***

My SecondController:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Insert(String inputF)
    {
      
        if (!ModelState.IsValid || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputF.Input))
        {
            return View(inputF);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("FinalIndex", "Final");
        }
    }
```

It does not let me do `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputF.Input)` because it shows the following:

[image]

So I then removed the `.Input` from `inputF.Input` and it still gave me the the unhandled message in the picture below

My View:

```
@using CustomerSimulatorApp.Models
@model TextInput 

<h2>Second page</h2>



@using (Html.BeginForm("Insert", "Second", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.Input);

    <input id="Button" type="submit" value="button" />

}
```

My model:

```
namespace CustomerSimulatorApp.Models
{
    public class TextInput
    {
        [Required, MinLength(1)] 
        public String Input { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I leave the text box empty & hit the button it returns this shown below:

[image]

*Not sure, if that is what is exactly supposed to happen or if an actual exception was supposed to be thrown. Also, when I just type a single character in the box and hit the button it still allows me to proceed to the redirect and does not throw an exception regardless of my `[Required MinLength(2)]` on my attribute.*

So my **objective** is to redirect the user to another page (`FinalIndex`) if the user typed something into the textbox and hits the button. If the user did not type anything in the text box and still hits the button to proceed to the next page, then it needs to throw an exception.

Am I doing something incorrectly? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated it!

Comment: Is your controller name `SecondController`?

Comment: @mxmissile Yes that is my controller name, I know its not the greatest just wanted to test some things. I will go and and change my action footprint

Comment: Nevermind on that last part, I just saw your Model, I thought TextInput was something else.

Comment: When you `return View(inputF);` its going to use the Action name: "Insert" for view location, make sure that exists.

Comment: Please see my updated code

Comment: I don't have a view for "Insert" because I thought the line `Html.BeginForm("Insert", "Second", FormMethod.Post)` was calling the `Insert` function inside of `SecondController`

Comment: Right, but you are returning "View()" in your Insert action. What is the name of your original action?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232834/discussion-between-novicecoder-and-mxmissile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We got this resolved over chat, just had a few naming conventions we changed:

```
  public IActionResult SecIndex(TextInput form)
```

Was the ultimate fix, instead returning a non-existing view.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, but few changes are needed in view and controller side to get it working.

- you need to have input button with type submit

  ```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Insert", "Second", FormMethod.Post))
  {
      @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.Input);

      <input id="Button" type="submit" value="button" />
  }
  ```

and in controller action code should be like:

```
// this if checks if input textbox value is not present load back page with error
if (!ModelState.IsValid || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputF.Input))
{
    return View(inputF);
}
else
{
     // there was value in input redirect to Final controller action
     return RedirectToAction("FinalIndex","Final");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!! I understand your logic! I implemented your suggestion and for some reason it says The view 'Insert' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Second/Insert.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Insert.cshtml

Comment: Is that what is supposed to return with the if statement? Or is it supposed to throw an exception?

Comment: Insert does exist because its a action inside of `secondcontroller`.... no idea why its searching for a view file

Comment: I noticed also that when I typed a single character in the text box it still proceeds... but I did an attribute in the Model class where it is `[Required, MinLength(1)]` is that not the correct way to do so? Was expecting it to throw an exception for that scenario

Comment: @NoviceCoder update the question with your updated code, show your changes.